# Difference between <%= ... %> and <% ... %> Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, scripting

Could someone explain the difference between using <%= *some_ruby_code* %> and <% *some_other_ruby_code* %>

I'm aware that they're not equivalent but can't find a good explanation as to why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ERB (Embedded Ruby), using `<%= %>` will both evaluate and *render* the evaluated Ruby within your markup, whereas just using `<% %>` will only evaluate the enclosed expression, and will not print anything to the erb file.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In other words, with <%= %> you execute ruby code and print the output. Using <% %> is only necessary to run the ruby code.

To clarify, this is Emebedded Ruby which you use for views pages on Rails. This might helpful for you: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html